# Why isn´t it possible to use a ng-keypress-event on an option-element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anybody know why it isn´t possible to use a angularjs keypress-event on an option-element?

```
<div><p><select ng-hide="see2" name="tagsField" size="3" ng-keypress="test($event)">
<option  ng-repeat="t in tags| filter: problem.tagsearch"  ng-dblclick="addChoosenTag(t.name)" >{{t.name}}</option>
</select></p></div>
```

works great.

But

```
<div><p><select ng-hide="see2" name="tagsField" size="3">
<option  ng-repeat="t in tags| filter: problem.tagsearch"  ng-dblclick="addChoosenTag(t.name) ng-keypress="test($event)"" >{{t.name}}</option>
</select></p></div>
```

doesn´t work. Is there any solution or a workaround for that problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The `<option>` element can't gain focus and so has no methods for `doubleclick`, `keypress`, etc. You need to add them to the `<select>` instead

Comment: Hi thanks for your Answer, but doubleclick works.

Comment: Not on an option element it doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Technically also if you go thorugh html elements you can have events on select not on option. So angular is also doing the same thing.

Now a solution would be to add it on select box and then have the selected option checked.

Answer (score -1):

OK I find a solution. Thanks for all of your help.

```
<div><select ng-hide="see2" name="tagsField" ng-keyup="getValue($event)" size="3" ng-model="selectedTag" ng-options="t.name for t in tags | filter: problem.tagsearch" ng-dblclick="addChoosenTag(selectedTag.name)">
<option value="">-- Auswählbare Tags --</option></select></p></div>
```